# How do I pass parent state to its child components?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am new in React ES6 and I think I am modifying the state in a wrong way. My code is like this when I set state on parent component:

```
class App extends React.Component  {
constuctor(props)  {
     super(props);
     this.state = {name:"helloworld"};
}
 render() { 
  return( 
   <ChildComponent parentObj={this} /> // parentObj for parent context as props on child components  
  ); 
 } 
}
```

My problem is in other child components, I have to do it repeatitively, is there another way of doing it? I have no problem with React.createClass, but I want to code in es6 so i have this problem.

Comment: [Lifting State Up](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html) and [Thinking in React](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html) will show you the more idiomatic way of doing these sorts of things.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you wanna pass the state {name:"helloworld"} do it like that:

```
class App extends React.Component {
constuctor(props)  {
     super(props);
     this.state = {name:"helloworld"};
}
 render() { 
  return( 
   <ChildComponent {...this.state} /> 
  ); 
 } 
}
```

and in the child component you can do:

```
<Text>{this.props.name}</Text>
```

But If you want to pass the props of the component to it's child:

```
   class App extends React.Component {
    constuctor(props)  {
         super(props);
         this.state = {name:"helloworld"};
    }
     render() { 
      return( 
       <ChildComponent {...this.props} />
      ); 
     } 
    }
```

and in the child component you can do:

```
<Text>{this.props.stuff}</Text>//place stuff by any property name in props
```

Now if you want to update the state of parent component from the child component you will need to pass a function to the child component:

```
 class App extends React.Component {
    constuctor(props)  {
         super(props);
         this.state = {name:"helloworld"};
    }
    update(name){
       this.setState({name:name})// or with es6 this.setState({name})
    }
    render() { 
     return( 
      <ChildComponent {...this.props, update: this.update.bind(this)} />
     ); 
    } 
  }
```

and then in child component you can use this : `this.props.update('new name')`

**UPDATE**

***use more es6 and removed constructor***

```
class App extends React.Component {
    state = {name:"helloworld"};

    // es6 function, will be bind with adding .bind(this)
    update = name => {
       this.setState({name:name})// or with es6 this.setState({name})
    }

    render() { 
     // notice that we removed .bind(this) from the update
     return(
     //send multiple methods using ','
      <ChildComponent {...this.props, update = this.update} />
     ); 
    } 
  }
```

Comment: I understand this, but can I make state changes from child components?

Comment: not directly, you can pass a function, let's say call it update, I will edit the answer to show you!

Comment: sorry, I was passing the method as props but I didn't know you can use bind and this on it,I was using it on constructor. Thank you! :)

Comment: @challenger hey! this was a great thorough answer. but I'm having some trouble implementing your suggestions, would really appreciate it if you could take a quick look here! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48970200/react-native-trouble-passing-parents-state-to-child

Comment: what is the parent's state was changed and you want the child to know? for example some Boolean in the state changed.

Comment: {...this.props, update: this.update} - i'm having a compilation error, when trying to add update prop. though {...this.props} update={this.update} works as expected. Is this a typo, or some babel magic?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to send the whole state :

```
return( <ChildComponent {...this.state} /> );
```

But this is likely a bad idea :)

edit: in your scenario, this sends a 'name' property to child component with value 'helloworld'

Comment: yes, i Understand that it send 'name' property but I have to do that so i can use this.setState on child components, it works, but somehow I think it's the 'wrong' way

Comment: why is that a bad idea?

Comment: If you send the state from parent down to children repeatitively, then your component model is probably not that good :)

Comment: So what's the alternative @Ji aSH ? If a parent has a large number of items in state (large arrays included) that are not needed in the child, how do you send just, say, 5 parent state items to a child?

Comment: @KelvinAitken I don't think it is a good idea to pass {...this.state} to the children. What about if instead you group them in an object and pass the object to the children

Comment: @challenger - How would you do this in TypeScript?