# React Native - Trouble passing parent's state to child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, components, parent-child

a React newbie having some issues passing down states and functions from Parent Component (`App` in this case) and accessing from Child Components (`Main` in this case). I'm sure it's one or two really simple mistakes, where am I getting tripped up?

Here is the project structure:

```
App
 |__ Rootstack
       |
       |__Favorites
       |__Main
```

And here is the stripped down code:

```
class Main extends React.Component {
  render() {
      return (
      <View>
         <Text>{this.props.favoritesList.length}</Text>
         <Card>
              onSwiped={() => {this.props.updateArray}} //the idea being that on a swipe, updateArray would add 1 to the 'favoriteList' in the parents state, and the favoritesList.length would update by +1.
         </Card>
      </View>
        );
    }
}

class Favorites extends React.Component {
          ....
    }

const RootStack = StackNavigator(
  {
    Main: {
      screen: Main},
    Favorites: {
      screen: Favorites}
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Main'
  }
);


export default class App extends Component<{}> {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        favoritesList: []
      };
    this.updateArr = this.updateArr.bind(this); //don't know if this is necessary?
    }

  updateArr=()=>{this.setState({ favoritesList: 
      [...this.state.favoritesList, 'new value']})};

  render() {
      return <RootStack {...this.state} updateArray={this.updateArr}/>;
    }
  }
```

Error I'm getting is [image] -- any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are trying to send props through navigator and access it through your components. You can't send props through navigator this way. Look [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4323) instead it may help you.

Comment: first no need to bind an arrow function secondly you are passing props to a stateless component and also for navigator to receive props directly not possible.

Answer (score 0):

***1-***

This is not correct

```
       <Card  ... props should be here!!---  >
          onSwiped={() => {this.props.updateArray}} //the idea being that on a swipe, updateArray would add 1 to the 'favoriteList' in the parents state, and the favoritesList.length would update by +1.
     </Card>
```

The correct answer is:

```
     <Card  
       onSwiped={() => {this.props.updateArray}} //the idea being that on a swipe, updateArray would add 1 to the 'favoriteList' in the parents state, and the favoritesList.length would update by +1.
      >
    </Card>
```

The meaning of the error is that the child of Card is expected to be an object and not .....

***2-***

`this.updateArr = this.updateArr.bind(this);` is not necessary since `updateArr = () => ...` is written in es6